# T sql remove zero till positive number

Tags: sql-server

I have values as below

```
200200016229862

200200017189701

200200017193807

as varchar
```

If i use below query

```
select cast((SUBSTRING(sales_ID, 5,11)) as varchar)

from products
```

Result as below

```
00016229862

00017189701

00017193807
```

**Question:**

How can i select query as below without zeros from beginning until positive number

```
16229862

17189701

17193807
```

I want to remove **all zeros**(0) from beginning **until positive numeric** (1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: select  LTRIM(REPLACE(cast((SUBSTRING(sales_ID, 5,11)) as varchar),'000',' '))

from products

Comment: what about for 0000 zero or 00000 zero at the beginning ?

Comment: `select cast('00016229862' as bigint) == 16229862`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(cast((SUBSTRING(sales_ID, 5, 11)) as int) as varchar)
    from products
```